# Serialize id in _id format with serializeId in Ember

Tags: ember.js

In my response from server i have id attribute like 'id'. But to update record i need to send in request id like '_id'. I try to use serializeId [serializeId](https://emberjs.com/api/ember-data/2.16/classes/DS.JSONSerializer/methods/serializeId?anchor=serializeId) method. My adapter looks like

```
import DS from 'ember-data'
import DataAdapterMixin from 'ember-simple-auth/mixins/data-adapter-
mixin'
import Ember from 'ember'
import Inflector from 'ember-inflector'

export default DS.JSONAPIAdapter.extend(DataAdapterMixin, {
  authorizer: 'authorizer:token',
  pathForType (modelName) {
    let underscored = Ember.String.underscore(modelName)
    return Inflector.inflector.pluralize(underscored)
  }
```

})
and voicemail serializer

```
import ApplicationSerializer from './application'
import DS from 'ember-data'
import Ember from 'ember'

export default ApplicationSerializer.extend(DS.EmbeddedRecordsMixin, {
  primaryKey: 'id',
  attrs: {
    history: {embedded: 'always'}
  },
  serializeIntoHash (data, type, snapshot, options) {
    let root = Ember.String.decamelize(type.modelName)
    data[root] = this.serialize(snapshot, options)
  },
  serializeId (snapshot, json, primaryKey) {
    let id = snapshot.id
    json['_id'] = id
  }
})
```

But serializeId method did not called during serializing. And in my payload i still get id like 'id' instead '_id'. How to solve my issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATED
I find in ember code that serializeId runs only if ds-serialize-id feature is enabled.

```
 serialize(snapshot, options) {
let json = {};

if (options && options.includeId) {
  if (isEnabled('ds-serialize-id')) {
    this.serializeId(snapshot, json, get(this, 'primaryKey'));
  } else {
    const id = snapshot.id;
    if (id) {
      json[get(this, 'primaryKey')] = id;
    }
  }
}
```

To run serializeId method i turn on ds-serialize-id property in enviroment.js

```
EmberENV: {
  FEATURES: {
    // Here you can enable experimental features on an ember canary build
    // e.g. 'with-controller': true
    'ds-serialize-id': true
  }
```

}

I think that isues solved.